# How to show image from downloadable url from firebase immediately on the first render in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

-I am rendering an image from the downloadable url of firebase in react, but the weird thing is that it is not rendered in the first time I go to see the image on that link. But after I press again that button, to show the image.

-Here is the piece of the code where I am getting the downloadable url and setting the state of array of urls:

```js
   setImages(adArray) {
       var imagesOfAds = [];
       var imagesOfBoolean = [];

       adArray.forEach((ad) => {
           imagesOfBoolean[ad.adId] = false;
           databaseStorageRef.child("AdImages/" + ad.adId + "/" + ad.imageOfTheAd).getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
               imagesOfAds[ad.adId] = url;
               imagesOfBoolean[ad.adId] = true;
           }).catch((err) => {
               imagesOfBoolean[ad.adId] = true;
               imagesOfAds[ad.adId] = '';
           });
           do {
               console.log(imagesOfBoolean);
           } while (!imagesOfBoolean);
       });

       this.setState({
           imagesOfAds: imagesOfAds,
           imagesSet: true
       })

       this.forceUpdate();
   }
```

-And here is where I am using that urls:

```js
<Col xs={7} md={4}>
  <a href="#" onClick={() => this.changePage(ad.adId, ad.phoneNumber)}>
    {" "}
    <h4>
      {" "}
      <b> {ad.title} </b>{" "}
    </h4>{" "}
  </a>{" "}
  <br />
  {self.state.imagesOfAds[ad.adId] != "" ? (
    <img
      src={self.state.imagesOfAds[ad.adId]}
      className="imageOfAd"
      onClick={() => this.setState({ showMaximizationDialog: true })}
    />
  ) : (
    <Image
      onClick={() => this.setState({ showMaximizationDialog: true })}
      src={require("./images/oglasi.jpg")}
      thumbnail
    />
  )}
</Col>;
```

-And this works fine, the only problem is that it is rendering after double click on that option which is rendering to me that image.

-Is there a way to faster this process? With just one click?